# onCompleted callback is not calling for 2nd call in useLazyQuery hook apollo client(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, graphql-js

I am using apollo client for react for graphql queries now i have an issue that while i am using useLazyQuery hook to query programatically but onCompleted callback is not triggering when i query for the 2nd time actually network request is completeng and the state in the 1 index of return value of that hook is updating

```
const [getUser, getUserStatus] = useLazyQuery(GET_USER, {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    // this callback is not triggering 2nd call of getUser
    onCompleted: (data) => {
        const { customerCart, customer } = data;
        if (!id) {
            dispatch(updateCartId(customerCart.id));
        }
        if (id !== customerCart.id) {
            mergeCart({
                variables: { cartId: id, cartIdToMerge: customerCart.id },
            });
        }
        dispatch(updateUser(customer));
    },
    onError: (error) => {
        checkHasAuth(error);
    },
});

useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
        // here i am calling first and 2nd time
        getUser();
    }
}, [getUser, token]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to make the variables of the following query different from the variables of the previous query.

for example:

```
getUser({
    variables: {
        state: Math.random(),
    },
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! To clarify, you can add an _arbitrary_ random variable to the query to work around apollo's 5-year-old-and-counting bug.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a known issue that Apollo's `onCompleted` option works differently between queries fulfilled over the network and by the cache. If the query can be fulfilled from the cache then `onCompleted` is not called, whereas if the query is fulfilled over the network via the server, then `onCompleted` *is* called.

You can set the `fetchPolicy` in the options that you pass to `useLazyQuery` to bypass the cache if you want to force the `onCompleted` callback to run:

```
const [loadData] = useLazyQuery(QUERY, {fetchPolicy: 'network-only', onCompleted: ...})
```

Github issue: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9338

Apollo docs for fetchPolicy options: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be apollo's default behavior, refer to their docs:

> By default, the useQuery hook checks the Apollo Client cache to see if all the data you requested is already available locally. If all data is available locally, useQuery returns that data and doesn't query your GraphQL server. This cache-first policy is Apollo Client's default fetch policy.

So, if you changed the `fetchPolicy` to `network-only` for example, it should work.